# How to make UILabel resize to fit text

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I have a UILabel that I have layed out in a storyboard centred in the view. It has some initial text "tap to login".

I am changing the value of the label to be the user's name once they have logged in. Once I do this, the label is no longer centered as the UILabel has not changed size.

How can I do this with autolayout in interface builder?

Comment: You need to show us the constraints you added in order to position the label.

Comment: you want to change the width of label according to their text ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

see this scrrenshot

1 first select your label width constraint

2 set the relation Greater than or equal

3 set the default constant value here i set it 10

when you change the label text it change the size of label according to its text. hope it's help :)

Comment: an additional point for anyone looking at this. Make sure you haven't set both leading & trailing constraints as those override 'greater than' constraints

Answer (score 1):

Iam guessing the label is not getting height and width, consider giving those constraints and then when your text changes use this method to determine the height and width:

```
    func labelSizeWithString(text: String, maxWidth : CGFloat,numberOfLines : Int) -> CGRect{
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, maxWidth, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame
}
```

Comment: OP wants to do it using Autolayout. You can't update the frame when using it.

Comment: you can get the updated height and width , then accordingly change the constraints for height and weight... kindly read my answer properly

Comment: It is an overkill and inefficient to create a UILabel just to get the width and height of a text. There is [`boundingRectWithSize(_:options:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize:options:context:) to do that. Besides getting width and height won't solve OP's problem regarding centering the label. He'll have to do lots of calculations to position the label to the center of its superview anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `UILabel` `frame.width` bigger, maybe the same width as the screen.

Then you set the

`label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter`

Answer (score 0):

1.showing initial text to label
2.After pressing button changing text, that showing in middle of screen 3.Look at constraints third image, two constraints given 1.top to view 2.horizontally middle in container
[image]

[image]

[image]

Another thing if u given fixed width for the label,change relation as more than equal.[Click width constraint ,see right side top there change the relation[image: ]]